# Ansible and Python Jinja2 filter for collection

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2, dokku

I want to add SSH keys to `dokku` in `Ansible`. When the key is already added I get the error like:

```
"\r\nDuplicate SSH Key name\r\nsshcommand returned an error: 255\r\n"
```

I can, of course, ignore it but I can know upfront if the key is added by running:

```
vagrant@vagrant:/home/dokku$ dokku ssh-keys:list
SHA256:dai6gOKjl1NMD1pre1104aF/Iz8Cfy8gmHdOx4RgZvs NAME="UserA""
SHA256:zYYrX2tXt95wRjXFHMcefFkSIHotulkU62kFoaFGV8c NAME="UserB""
```

Is there any way to check if a user is already defined? Something like:

```
- name: authorize developers
  raw:  dokku ssh-keys:add {{ item }} {{ ssh_dir }}/{{ item }}.pub
  when: "{{ item }} not in keys.stdout_lines"
  with_items: "{{ developers }}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like the following:

```
- name: sshcommand list dokku
  command: sshcommand list dokku
  changed_when: False
  register: dokku_ssh_users
  ignore_errors: true

- name: dokku ssh-keys:add
  shell: 'key=$(cat "{{ item.value }}"); echo "$key" | dokku ssh-keys:add {{ item.key }}'
  when: dokku_ssh_users is defined and dokku_ssh_users.stdout.find(item.key) == -1
  with_dict:
    username: path/to/key
```

Comment: `when` statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters

Comment: I modified the answer to remove them, it should work fine.